# mysql select table names of similar tables

Tags: mysql

I made one table for every client. For example client_001, client_002, client_003, etc.

It is possible to do a select like:

select tableNames from MyDB where table_name like 'client_';

where result:

### tableNames

client_001

client_002

client_003

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick

```
SELECT * FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`TABLES` WHERE
  `table_schema` = 'MY_DATABASE' AND `table_name` LIKE 'client_%';
```

Or (not sure on this one, but I think it works)

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE 'client_%';
```

Note that the first one can be used as a subquery, while the second (I don't think) cannot.

See docs for `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`TABLES`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/tables-table.html